# Javascript validation - Min/Max number of characters AND must contain number

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have the following problem:

I need to validate an input (password field) with Javascript / jQuery

The rules are:

it must be 8 to 32 characters
it must contain letters AND at least one number

So my logic is the following but I can't seem to be able to implement it

be 8 to 32

```
if it's NOT 8 to 32 characters and doesn't have numbers
{
    jQuery('#passwordfield').addClass('error');
}
```

I tried the following (just with 0 as number, for test purposes)

```
if(((jQuery('#passwordfield').val().length <= 7) || (jQuery('#passwordfield').val().length >= 33)) && ((jQuery('#passwordfield').val().indexOf("0") == -1)))
{
     jQuery('#passwordfield').addClass('error');
}
```

The problem with the above code is that it returns true if you type enough characters (8 to 32) and NOT contain a number since the first part of the && is true

Comment: Look into [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: If you're looking at HTML5 only you can probably add this directly to the HTML fields as a regex pattern rather than add additional JS code.

Comment: @Mooseman: How would you check if there is at least one number? The length and only numbers and letters would work with `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,32}$/` but how to make sure that it is not only numbers or only letters?

Comment: A little off-toppic but keep it in mind: Restricting the user in such ways prevents them from using pass phrases, which provide similar security and are preferred by some users.

Comment: I agree @LarsEbert but it's really not up to me to decide that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
var p = jQuery('#passwordfield').val();
if(p.length <=7 || p.length >= 33 || !p.match(/\d/) || !p.match(/[a-z]/i))
    $('.whatever').addClass('error');
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `||` instead of `&&`, since all criteria must be met?

Comment: Yes, but it is negative, if one of these for checks is true, the password is invalid and must be marked as error. Proof: `length <= 7 && length >= 33` can never be true, as a number can not be both larger than 32 and smaller than 8. English: if length smaller 8 **or** length bigger 32 **or** password contains no digit **or** password contains no letter then the password is invalid.

Comment: I am still curious: Would it be possible to check this all in **one single** regular expression?

Comment: @LarsEbert I can easily check if the string contain atleast 1 letter and 1 digit in a single regular expression, but for the length, i can't think of something...

Comment: @Stevenson Don't worry about it, i've asked a question that got down voted i don't know why. What's important here is that you got your answer no? The downvotes were probably because of a lack of search effort since you could have find your answer on google (I didn't try to tough)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon yeah not worrying about it and I did try google but it's not as easy as you guys think. For instance, if I googled "regular expressions" I could solve it my self, but the point is that I didn't know that regular expressions would solve my problem! :)

Comment: @LarsEbert Actually, here, it work with 1 regexp (I think)! http://jsfiddle.net/6V447/

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression:-

```
var val = jQuery('#passwordfield').val();
if(val.length <=7 || val.length >= 33 || !/[0-9]/.test(val) || !/[a-zA-Z]/.test(val))
{
// show error
}
```

Comment: That's literally the same answer as Karl-André Gagnons ;)

Comment: Sorry, I have not seen his answer when I saw the question. It was posted later.

Answer (score 0):

String must contain 0..* letters and 1..* numbers (with a total length of 8..32):

```
if (str.search(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,32}$/) == -1 || str.search(/\d/) == -1) {
    jQuery('#passwordfield').addClass('error');
}
```

String must contain 1..* letters and 1..* numbers (with a total length of 8..32):

```
if (str.search(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,32}$/) == -1 || str.search(/[a-zA-Z]\d|\d[a-zA-Z]/) == -1) {
    jQuery('#passwordfield').addClass('error');
}
```

Comment: This would allow passwords containing only digits. Add `str.search(/[a-z]/i)` to make it perfect!

Comment: Well he said '... contains letters' (0 or more) 'and AT LEAST one number.'

Comment: *"must contain letters **AND** at least one number"*. Your expression allow `00000000` as password.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon See my previous comment (and edit).